# How do I get the id or name of an element in watir?

Tags: watir

Watir can find a text on a page:

```
<span id="i1" name="n1>Some Text</span>

e.text.include?("Some Text")
```

But how can I get the name or id of the span, when I only know "Some Text"

```
e.text.findInPage("Some Text").parentElement.id (should be "i1")
e.text.findInPage("Some Text").parentElement.name (should be "n1");
```

Something like this exists in watir?

Comment: `name="n1` should be `name="n1"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
browser.span(:text => "Some Text").id
=> "i1"

browser.span(:text => "Some Text").name
=> "n1"
```

Tested on Windows, Ruby 1.8.6, Watir 1.6.5, Internet Explorer driver.